# Excessive delay or not delivery for Yahoo emails to Exchange mailboxes

Tags: email, email-server, exchange-2010, mailbox

Emails with attachments from Yahoo mail not deliver to our exchange mailboxes or receive with to much delay.The bigger the attachment the later delivery.Emails with 10MB attachments not deliver at all and "Failure Notice" message appear in yahoo mailbox.
Receive connector maximum size set to 15MB and sending same emails from gmail deliver successfully to our mailboxes.
Analyzing header of delivered Yahoo mails shows that delay occurs between internal yahoo servers:

```
Received: from edge.mydomain.com (...) by hubtransport.mydomain.com
 (...) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.3.361.1; Tue, 17 Oct
 2017 09:46:19 +0330
Received: from sonic301-2.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com (74.6.129.41) by
 edge.mydomain.com (...) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 14.1.438.0; Tue,
 17 Oct 2017 09:42:10 +0330
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s2048; t=1508220732; bh=bksjW5TROZcxTvYHCLqUYpF9HOWQ9JF0oMeKW5qc+uY=; h=Date:From:Reply-To:To:In-Reply-To:References:Subject:From:Subject; b=phTCEcma9Zp3i5o5U3hPunGTiqrIBBn8vXKX8XV847eQ/YYbxaqNQ6in+hTiiB4nepTLME7idDYC52Jo/1Yu3o3MmCebT849+/6bq32hmB9ynTiWdqcWAEKhXLmXSlammDKB0shbHG26rC7VX840V2NtxKLB5QMLYxgHbgCVgh5gFaPsd6yP1Pz0XLIwI59n619lDrtHQYcAW2ghtTukh3I2UMByuteAJKYC/d/eq8eoayen14xMgcc/J08osx4MAtcLPl5PenXzBQpTf+hgUljqixKjKiBVZ1+D8OtVRwrD7qT13pj95YOPJHqr3Sjs28uLaaL1HZdbu9f9PTZQSw==
X-YMail-OSG: bPRSVbgVM1mj9nLbjTnKbn5kHc._OmtaBeC0DmqQFJdYlBvKo1Z1LJj7IM28zQs
 F0grQ1hFHudHa_8YL.jM.3gxQjhZq45uEbgAYQE1QOyOZgijZuRWYwqFKseJ1koAiJMvByg_810l
 CdN.03xyqzjrg90iYKGQQFlQDS3R2sVT5Emo4o30_6qD..FEKvVAFLLHpNXMKjQLxxljH03MRdWk
 0Kq9PYqzhHe1s50rA.ldANwdftqBEDnpJzUiirf..iYYgpBtV8kxSXtMkqnE5jF5YnbgZGudTrVj
 cTCBDAQAfDyixUpmj0sB9VHdU6Kenec6fkqmwJGfoZj4_U4l_brm30KxU9DItRSoKYg9Ypr.trIA
 7BThj_iBPzWpK4XVT_FytNOr5GINp_FaUTYlj.EqsTgfEPQ6Pf3TtIgmqvs.AjCdAKT4_ciz2..Q
 Kz6T8hAxAbbetbGTPCPwMdtFw41s3sXu62tj6Jeoffh.Q2Fu.YlM8cewZOM86Xz.0.dkLUNPAEEs
 -
Received: from sonic.gate.mail.ne1.yahoo.com by
 sonic301.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com with HTTP; Tue, 17 Oct 2017 06:12:12 +0000
Date: Tue, 17 Oct 2017 06:00:02 +0000
From: test <test@yahoo.com>
To: =?UTF-8?B?2YbbjNmF2Kcg2LTYp9uM2YI=?= <test@mydomain.com>
Message-ID: <...@mail.yahoo.com>
Subject: 929
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_Part_322010_1330634417.1508220003126"
X-Mailer: WebService/1.1.10774 YahooMailNeo Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Content-Length: 5861292
Return-Path: test@yahoo.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PRD: yahoo.com
Received-SPF: Pass (...)
 client-ip=74.6.129.41; helo=sonic301-2.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Antispam-Report: DV:3.3.16312.857;SID:SenderIDStatus Pass;OrigIP:74.6.129.41
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SenderIdResult: PASS
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: edg.mydomain.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
```

Pay attention to "Date" header and delay in receiving email from from sonic.gate.mail.ne1.yahoo.com to sonic301.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com with HTTP in "Received" header which is almost 12 minute.
Obviously Sending email from yahoo to gmail don't suffer from such problem but the different internal yahoo server are in use in that.

**Update:**
Blow is the returned "Failure Notice" email to Yahoo mailbox:

```
X-Apparently-To: test@mydomain.com; Tue, 17 Oct 2017 10:39:58 +0000
Return-Path: <>
Received-SPF: none (domain of sonic309-13.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com does not designate permitted sender hosts)
X-YMailISG: EyD_Pj4WLDvW5UziFeMPpsIVOtNXaMd1k80he9MFvw2jTbMD
 FQ.Ct3tOPTQH7kF9.y7CKUy2tg5OEiKv4wau.h2wfsQFnFYxArH9Y8hGnNp6
 m1_shZNNK9bkroRxhmCZEOP5Q.z3dbT97ypq048LwaYKcXENkKtpO8WSScSU
 7EqB1A7ZYvX37Yj8G8AsItNSbd_G34wpB9zEgTvrZfr4G6LN6UjhT71Cd15I
 C.CgBJKXCHsANyNlzghnA4L59Jz5FULsMK8EKDN4b8HE0emYJh4jgR0sgr.R
 _D0MXr2aYJhgwTiEHeRYWaEX_3Q1RlxAkSMOFcG6c1VOFdSY1uYiJLX0yASD
 eSnrFiLilvIZGjmf3JNPK1n1pYbsw4.0eiyOVWx9.bRMVeWFKAyp767BvdT.
 efrKX1rLQ9geOldqyq0QhvlHf4ua4WLew13h7oNz.UftMTj.kbb1FSIcli5V
 QLMXPA6dcAMWA4bb9kCJxs7fwFK7yce_dEJoBtmqINi8Zbtgbvte40qvOtP8
 4XYSffz3F2ZF8N7uqRFOI7Ve77Qg0ro5joiXZK0ssex6qxu9ckRpHM95GU0B
 OhcGvTnYMomCii2hrK1IqG4ELjTou9M9fGR4XTmFQEqtSr3lqOjURS0Hjwbk
 nSqpNDmt3TEs2xmXtH1L92gfBEMiT_V34R6j0076MXly59YTEsFVpKZGggy4
 m3kfHdNxs2yrH3VV.6Q8tGqm6D5AplLKHlpkmzpTuPZHUZgM.rwbDSvADG1A
 cyg5IlpD63Fd4j_.dKUlp290xY7ti_yYJdCve6uLihiujxmcQ0yW9L688I34
 4ew.E1X_cbzkhCx7XfVCFkLgZRf.VGyQNOlBlN2kKogb8_5qwiDIa.S8zwqZ
 .bUo7c6CfHlbH81gHDAAdIkCT8IBnrcIUwf7fhrKwhevrn.4hd0kpFGOf9YN
 M3gE70lzayzkZLnw12Z7WgSI56PMkdI_7cVBs5nk4HBbhfG8Y77AVYokSNnB
 4pg3KaJ2xIb0uVkdGKata4CdVkxaYC3OltXUGKlCfVeQTitPbd10nskVAXxD
 pfxNeGG592s5t2rkIpK87WvhSXsDqvCei5qtRMyzCsTCKtIootgfxHjJQxAR
 kpjm2UT0xNFbQ7Txn3Xalb.y8yQhIN1mXTs6koaTvd5AiUCQTZhv8drvfueR
 qW6ldJ2Cjn60_VnRAPf_9X9ZB8ouG8XTj7R3SKw1XpN_8iB0MF21Z2kCV.M0
 D6nW7vE_cfwxRRlZCtPdQxkCra0BkX63RuCxNIKWVsH3AG2K7arHEacYRPi_
 oXJ1bSubccNmrMxJfXxpSQEZqy51CifFwXoqkf6sYulnu6vrtz1xCriuBLkS
X-Originating-IP: [74.6.129.123]
Authentication-Results: mta1038.mail.gq1.yahoo.com  from=yahoo.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=yahoo.com; dkim=pass (ok)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO sonic309-13.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com) (74.6.129.123)
  by mta1038.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Tue, 17 Oct 2017 10:39:58 +0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=bounce; t=1508236797; bh=HBViP8ksLRRBMVsngkSc1xd9E7HF0hs0Z7TUk1trgs0=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:From:Subject; b=Akywhnxfnu7B79RDSgA6WFjQAKR1xM5sCfUQ/swEFWkRRcHife7JjAYE6FZT8Tc006bo4d3jHb5AVyDGoyEmTyp6An/Hm6+WhaZHDrmYfpaUZCe+w4AP2YtpT6Mr8gpcmCqQyYBHlWhxgPVX7umjai7rPt4xpIuNqi6TRplB2m4=
Received: from sonic.gate.mail.ne1.yahoo.com by sonic309.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com with HTTP; Tue, 17 Oct 2017 10:39:57 +0000
Date: Tue, 17 Oct 2017 10:39:57 +0000
From: MAILER-DAEMON@yahoo.com
To: test@mydomain.com
Message-ID: <829224876.370562.1508236797219@sonic309.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com>
Subject: Failure Notice
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Length: 30563

Sorry, we were unable to deliver your message to the following address.

<test@mydomain.com>:
Unable to deliver message after multiple retries, giving up.

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s2048; t=1508236495; bh=05+txvVD/0X1C1jzEbs51ITk3qlI/U56iABbC6omHQc=; h=Date:From:To:In-Reply-To:References:Subject:From:Subject; b=mDp0ROYHIb64wmkZedr5AJ5Tr+D0DBAlQ8E2oW5ZO7V/BzqYof89/le/xR4xdUiRCMCJ0fDKNFFcs54nsgCt/QJ092SpLvkvBoFP37Y5TU0OWOH7M8zmoIAcyfYLQyC9HReYaWgcwkWyD6d70AXwOyE93ReApl46xo3+/ocm8zugO7T5RqtrsQmK5Ufr0GKo7scE6q9K0Crfcdke2FX3xQ55Xctr/JW4R+5KUgmw4iKZzOmlvz7XTj4baSp5fkNURkKkjViihYyZnjzdu2Wdi4mZaLMxFWmaTy3aUBOtvptJTG18if3zNcqCtWmQQEsyU4wTRGd/p8hfCygb0cly2g==
X-YMail-OSG: 8U.aQjsVM1nQWEX9W4_6faDyxdY3HwSgCPyG5deJnM2q5PD8vG8Dz6FJPMm4gVa
 fNvkk6oB8kwLRbFQ98skbWm2v5zzaEbRehoj7fEZtylioWiy4D13HNYIdX42sY.OXj1K5jRkFGiw
 IW56WSiD652kP.yuOzuNE5_mADT5Bry4g.M_Lhfpsg42.hTW0xsYAyFac0UWeLTUy6tLjWBSaLbb
 lGcyjCeGY58ifsKrc8zNfiZsdHiYt35.XT8oBiMEKppl6KUpTXfnthUTqmb1ZrcIJyTDPs4xYqna
 REbEHPqyBSgAUa8dScrwFvcdrQfshXmiIEfU.Wd35A4OKVZYZxzDnQ8TuK5ttXpigMwna7bq_tvZ
 DncMPlWs7PuVcBdrDLkW2ID0_8U5eRsXz6yzTVkwSQYFppDOlxxoQiHLx9b5dbNP76OShzk8hhO3
 nwe8cn.EN_Q.RMkN4HlajXaGziE.7SH5XPurm.NXGkHm_Zdxz17O0JAj86Wg-
Received: from sonic.gate.mail.ne1.yahoo.com by sonic309.consmr.mail.bf2.yahoo.com with HTTP; Tue, 17 Oct 2017 10:34:55 +0000
Date: Tue, 17 Oct 2017 07:36:05 +0000 (UTC)
From: test <test@mydomain.com>
To: =?UTF-8?B?2KzZiNin2K8g2LTYudin2LnbjA==?= <test@mydomain.com>
Message-ID: <1001794763.351576.1508225766737@mail.yahoo.com>
In-Reply-To: <2076977144.308793.1508219707757@mail.yahoo.com>
References: <2076977144.308793.1508219707757.ref@mail.yahoo.com> <2076977144.308793.1508219707757@mail.yahoo.com>
Subject: Fw: scasdfddd
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_351575_1109119668.1508225766737"
X-Mailer: WebService/1.1.10774 YMailNorrin Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Content-Length: 11219432

------=_Part_351575_1109119668.1508225766737
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_351568_178096500.1508225765923"

------=_Part_351568_178096500.1508225765923
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

   ----- Forwarded Message ----- From: test <test@mydomain.com>To: =
=D8=AC=D9=88=D8=A7=D8=AF =D8=B4=D8=B9=D8=A7=D8=B9=DB=8C <test@mydomain.com>
Sent: Tuesday, October 17, 2017, 9:25:08 AM GMT+3:30Subject: scasdfddd
 dfdsfsffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
 =20
------=_Part_351568_178096500.1508225765923
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head></head><body><div style=3D"font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetic=
a, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;"><div></div>
            <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br></div><div><br></div>
           =20
            <div id=3D"ydp23e139d9yahoo_quoted_8242600409" class=3D"ydp23e1=
39d9yahoo_quoted">
                <div style=3D"font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Aria=
l, sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#26282a;">
                    <div>----- Forwarded Message -----</div>
                    <div><b>From:</b> test &lt;test@mydomain.com&gt=
;</div><div><b>To:</b> =D8=AC=D9=88=D8=A7=D8=AF =D8=B4=D8=B9=D8=A7=D8=B9=DB=
=8C &lt;test@mydomain.com&gt;</div><div><b>Sent:</b> Tuesday, October 17,=
 2017, 9:25:08 AM GMT+3:30</div><div><b>Subject:</b> scasdfddd</div><div><b=
r></div>
                    <div><div style=3D"font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetic=
a, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;"><div>dfdsfsffffffffffffffffffffffffff=
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff<br></div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div></div></body></html>
------=_Part_351568_178096500.1508225765923--

------=_Part_351575_1109119668.1508225766737
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Microsoft Lync Server 2013  Step by
 Step for Anyone_REV014.pdf"
Content-ID: <b088c57a-957b-2761-59c8-16dcf0766adc@yahoo.com>
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[remainder of message body omitted; too large]
```

Comment: Are you asking us why the email is delayed internally by Yahoo? We wouldn't know. You need to speak to Yahoo support or contact the Yahoo postmaster.

Comment: As yahoo support is not good even about their mailboxes let alone their server problems and maybe my assumptions about the problem would be  wrong I consult others about it.

Comment: I do not see a yahoo internal delay I see a 30min delay between yahoo and your environment (see [here](https://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=e324d336-ca81-4b4f-a476-fddb221c7dde)). So to troubleshoot that we need logs from your Exchange server to check what happened here. It would be also great to get a header from the email which isn´t delivered. Maybe we found there something to troubleshoot the issue... There must be a reason why the email wasn´t delivered and this should be inside the header including the server who rejected that. Can you post that here as well please?

Comment: I saw Mxtoolbox header analyzer earlier and I think it doesn't analyze correct.You would see different result from https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/
And as I mentioned delay appear in first "Received" header (down-up) which is between yahoo servers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to Yahoo internal servers which is discussed [here](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Temporary-Errors/Unable-to-deliver-message-after-multiple-retries-giving-up-As-of/td-p/237389). Maybe they apply some changes to their servers as now only emails with attachments encounter such problems not all of them.